# How to change itemsPerPageLabel in mat-paginator (Angular 4)

Tags: angular

I'm working with Angular 4 and I need to change paginator's value "Items per page". How can I get this value?

HTML:

```
<mat-paginator class="mat-paginator" #paginator [length]="table_data && table_data.resultsLength" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 100]" [pageSize]="customerMessageService.rowsNumber">
</mat-paginator>
```

In documentation is said:

```
To modify the labels and text displayed, create a new instance of MatPaginatorIntl and include it in a custom provider
```

I imported {MatPaginatorModule} from "@angular/material" and put MatPaginatorIntl in providers.

What should I do then in my .ts file?

Is it right to put this in my component.ts?

```
export class MatPaginatorIntl {
  itemsPerPageLabel = "1234";
}
```

Comment: Wow the docs are bad. See here https://github.com/koiszzz

Comment: I am still looking for the correct docs to implement this. any help?

Answer (score 5):

To customize/change the itemsPerPageLabel we need to extends MatPaginatorIntl class in your Component class and also need to provide in providers array inside your module. 

**app.component.ts**-

```
import {MatPaginatorIntl} from '@angular/material';

export class AppComponent extends MatPaginatorIntl {

 itemsPerPageLabel = 'custome_label_name';//customize item per page label

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

**app.component.html-**

```
 <mat-paginator> </mat-paginator>
```

**app.module.ts-**

```
import { MatPaginatorIntl, MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatPaginatorModule
  ]
    providers: [
    { provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: AppComponent }
  ]
})
```

---

We can also change following labels from MatPaginatorIntl class :-

- itemsPerPageLabel: string; 
    (*A label for the page size selector.*)
- nextPageLabel: string; 
      (*A label for the button that increments the current page.*)
- previousPageLabel: string; 
      (*A label for the button that decrements the current page.*)
- firstPageLabel: string; 
     (*A label for the button that decrements the current page.*)
- lastPageLabel: string; 
      (*A label for the button that moves to the last page.*)

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a dream